# Trying to run ifup and ifdown using linux capability

Tags: permissions, sudo

I want to run ifup eth0 and ifdown eth0  without sudo by using linux capabilities .

For the same issue i have written code for the same main.c

```
int main
{
FILE ,*fp;
fp  = popen("ifdown eth0","r");
if(fp==NULL)
{
printf("popen falied\n");
}
pclose(fp);
}
```

If i have set capabilities to binary like following-

```
sudo   setcap -v cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_dac_read_search,cap_net_admin+epi main
```

All the capabilities are set. It is verified by using getcap command

```
getcap main
main = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_net_admin+eip
```

if run above code i get following reply

```
./main

ifdown: failed to open lockfile /run/network/ifstate.eth0: Permission denied
```

although I have set capabilities for the permission still i am getting permission denied error.

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ./main`?

Comment: it works with sudo ./main . But i want to run it without sudo and by using Linux Capability i want to run it like this  ./main